# React Material UI OutlinedInput does not display error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Am using React and material UI to display an outlined input.  I can make it display that there has been an error with the `error` prop set to `true` but there is an issue when i try to add `helperText` and my message as a prop:

```
<OutlinedInput
  margin="dense"
  value=""
  placeholder="my placeholder"
  error
  helperText="There has been an error" // Property 'helperText' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & OutlinedInputProps'
/>
```

Is there any way to use both an `OutlinedInput` and display an error helper message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using base input component which is being used by TextField internally. If you've some special requirement you can compose your own text field like given [here](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#components).
Otherwise use `TextField` with variant="outlined":

```
       <TextField
          margin="dense"
          value=""
          placeholder="my placeholder"
          error
          helperText="There has been an error"
          variant="outlined"
        />
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use `FormHelperText` component from `@material-ui/core`.

```js
const [accountId, setAccountId] = useState({ value: "", error: "" });

<FormControl variant="outlined">
  <InputLabel htmlFor="accountId">Account Id</InputLabel>
  <OutlinedInput
    value={accountId.value}
    onChange={(e) => setAccountId({value: e.target.value, error:""})}
    inputProps={{
      "aria-label": "Account Id",
    }}
    labelWidth={74}
    error={!!accountId.error}
  />
  {!!accountId.error && (
    <FormHelperText error id="accountId-error">
      {accountId.error}
    </FormHelperText>
  )}
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<TextField/>` with  `variant="outlined"`
Here is the [CSB-Project Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-p2ks5?file=/demo.js:501-519)

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: "25ch"
    }
  }
}));

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <TextField
        id="outlined-basic"
        label="Outlined"
        variant="outlined"
        margin="dense"
        value=""
        placeholder="my placeholder"
        error
        helperText="There has been an error"
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```